# laravel 4 validation issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have this code in Controller store function to validate values of input tags

```
 $c = count(Input::get('division-name') );

   $divs_ids =  Input::get('division-name');

   $grade_name =Input::get('grade-name');

   // this loop for multiple values that insert from tags input.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c ; $i++){

   $rules[$i] = 'required|min:5';

   $msgs =  array('required' => 'Division name is required ','min' => 'the :attribute must be at least 5 characters. ') ; 


         }

    $validateDivision = Validator::make($divs_ids,$rules,$msgs);

    $validateGrade = Validator::make(Input::all(),Grade::$rules,Grade::$msgs);


      if ($validateDivision->fails() OR $validateGrade->fails()) {

          $validationMessages = array_merge_recursive($validateGrade->messages()->toArray(),
                                                      $validateDivision->messages()->toArray());            


             return    Redirect::back()->withErrors($validationMessages)->withInput();


    }else{
                  ..............
```

The issue, that the validation message of min validation

show  >>>  The 0 must be at least 5 characters.

how i can toggle (0) by the input name, or toggle (0) to start of (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values that will be replacing the :attribute tag in your error message will be the keys of your `$divs_ids` array.

But laravel allows you to use custom attributes name.

First you need to create an array containing your attributes name.
You can do that in the for loop you already have :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $c ; $i++){
    $rules[$i] = 'required|min:5';
    $customAttributes[$i] = 'Division name n°' . $i + 1; //For exemple
}
```

Now you can use that array like this:

```
$validateDivision = Validator::make($divs_ids,$rules,$msgs);
$validateDivision->setAttributeNames($customAttributes);
```

This way, your error message should display the custom attributes names.

Comment: thanks Mr Shibby for your help,
I did as you exactly mentioned it's working well now (0) have changed to (1)
but for all tags input , in other words now become (1) fixed it not increases according 
for the tags inputs index

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just

Change  `$customAttributes[$i] = 'Division name n°' . $i + 1;`

To      `$customAttributes[$i] = $i + 1;`

Comment: I think the your custom message can be declared outside the loop.

Comment: yeah you right , i tried it outside the loop worked well also .